# Allow users to add their own domain name to my server and make it HTTPS (SSL)

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, https

I'm creating a website builder where the user can sign up, and it will create a subdomain someuser.sitebuilder.com. At the moment it's not SSL as I'm waiting for LetsEncrypt to launch the wildcard SSL service in January.

However, the user can also their domain name, and I want that to be HTTPS too.

At the moment the user points www.someuser.com to dns.sitebuilder.com which works fine. My service is not live yet, but it's about to launch and thought I might tackle this before I do.

I'm using EC2 (via https://forge.laravel.com). I have all my other services using SSL, but I don't where to start with implementing it for users domain names?

Comment: Whatever method you use to add or identify that subdomain, you'd need to add a hook once DNS is updated to verify and add that certificate and reload the service.

Comment: Thanks, I thought it would be something like that. Do you have references or tutorials you know about that I could read on?

Comment: Look at the cpanel implementation.